# How to disable Ember showing 'null' for empty string

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I create a record I try to get the Model like this:

## controller/posts.js

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    createPost: function() {
      var newPost = this.get('store').createRecord('post', this.get('post'));
      newPost.set('date' , new Date());
      newPost.set('author' , 'C.L.I. Ember');
      this.get('target').transitionTo('post', newPost.save());
    }
  }
});
```

Working example: https://github.com/broerse/ember-cli-blog

This will post 'null' for empty strings.

How should this `this.get('post')`  be done correctly?

Comment: I guess you're trying to clone the post? `this.get('post')` is not a hash of values, which is what `createRecord` wants. You'll need to find other ways to clone Ember models, googling will turn things up.

Comment: googling does give me someting like    `this.get('store'),createRecord('post', model.toJSON());` but how do I get the model from the posts controller?

Comment: `this.get('model').toJSON()` does not seem to work.

Comment: Specify values one-by-one. `post = this.get('post'); newPost = this.store.craeteRecord('post', {field1: post.get('field1'), ...});`.

Comment: Yes this you can do but you will define the model structure in two places. I like to be able to move the CRUD actions from all controllers to some route, like the application route, in the future so defining the structure in the actions is not an option.

Comment: I'm not aware of any clean way to clone an Ember model instance, Your best bet is to add a model method called `clone`, and define it as `clone: function() { return this.store('post', this.getProperties('field`', 'field2', ...)); }`. There are certainly ways to get a list of model properties by mucking around inside the object, but I doubt if you want to go that way.

Comment: @torazaburo I found a way but am not sure it should be done this way. See http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-clone-copy-the-model-to-createrecord-in-the-controller/6200/3

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is using `defaultValue` in the model like this:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

var Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: ""}),
    author: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: ""}),
    date: DS.attr('date'),
    excerpt: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: ""}),
    body: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: ""}),
    rev: DS.attr('string')
});

export default Post;
```